# How do I use Java 8 groupingBy to collect into a list of a different type?

Tags: java, java-8, reducing, groupingby

I'm trying to take a map of type `A -> A`, and group it into a map of `A to List<A>`. (Also reversing the key-value relationship, but I don't think that is necessarily relevant).

This is what I have now:

```
private static Map<Thing, List<Thing>> consolidateMap(Map<Thing, Thing> releasedToDraft) {

    // Map each draft Thing back to the list of released Things (embedded in entries)
    Map<Thing, List<Map.Entry<Thing, Thing>>> draftToEntry = releasedToDraft.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(
                    Map.Entry::getValue,
                    toList()
            ));

    // Get us back to the map we want (Thing to list of Things)
    return draftToEntry.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    ThingReleaseUtil::entriesToThings
            ));
}

private static List<Thing> entriesToThings(Map.Entry<Thing, List<Map.Entry<Thing, Thing>>> entry) {
    return entry.getValue().stream()
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .collect(toList());
}
```

I'd like to do this in a single statement, and I feel like it must be possible to transform the `Map<Thing, List<Map.Entry<Thing, Thing>>>` to `Map<Thing, List<Thing>>` as part of the `groupingBy` operation.

I've tried using `reducing()`, custom collectors, everything I can find; but I'm stymied by the lack of complex examples out there, and the fact that the few similar ones I can find have `List.of()`, which doesn't exist in Java 8 (`Collections.singletonList()` does not appear to be a good replacement).

Could someone help me with what is probably the obvious?

Comment: In lieu of `List.of()` you can use `Arrays.asList()`.  Besides, `List.of()` creates an immutable list so you need to wrap it in a `constructor` of your favorite `List` implementation if you want to modify it.

Comment: @Scary Wombat could you tell me what you edited and why? There's no edit comment and the diff doesn't seem to show any changes.

Comment: Just formatted your code, but it looks likes you did some reformatting at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Must be on the line of

```
private static Map<Thing, List<Thing>> consolidateMap(Map<Thing, Thing> releasedToDraft) {
        return releasedToDraft.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(
                        Map.Entry::getValue,
                        mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, toList())
                ));
    }
```

Comment: I see where I made my mistake.  The key/values were reversed.  So it works.  Try this.   `Map<Integer, Integer> map = Map.of(1, 1, 3, 1, 5, 1, 6, 2, 8, 2, 10, 2);`  Use that as your test map.  It will then have 1 map to a list of odd values and 2 map to a list of even values.  So my original statement was wrong.  Your answer works just fine.

Comment: Nice answer. Just a minor change would be good, about inconsistent `static import` of `Collectors.` APIs. Either import all static changing `Collectors.mapping` to `mapping` or the other way. Aside: If an existing answer(as you've linked) already solves the question, flag it as a duplicate.

Comment: @Naman  I use eclipse and quite frankly it's support of static classes is not all that great.  They aren't as "sticky" as the other imports.

Comment: @WJS Well, on the contrary, I don't really use Eclipse. But if it's not sticky then all of those should usage should be `Collectors.` qualified, as in `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())))`. The primary motive was to ask to ensure consistency irrespective of whichever is preferred.

Comment: @WJS what do you mean with “sticky”? I have no problems with Eclipse and `import static` here…

Comment: @holger  Sticky was a poor choice of words.  Even if there is only one option, you have to explicitly check it.  For the example  above, I would have to click on each static method separately to have  it included. It would be much more friendly if it worked the same as non-static imports.  But I've gotten so used to typing in the class name I don't mess with it.  Perhaps I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @WJS in the Preferences, there is Java ‣ Editor ‣ Content Assist ‣ Favorites. There, I have the most important classes like `java.util.Arrays`, `java.util.Collections`, and `java.util.stream.Collectors`, so their methods are suggested on completion. One level higher, i.e. in “Content Assist”, there is “Add import instead of qualified name” and its sub-item “Use static imports”, which I have always toggled on.

Comment: @Holger Thanks!  But I have tried all that and it does work as advertised.  The issue I have is that if you make one mistake after completing the expression, and then proceed, planning to fix it later, they will disappear if you then type Ctrl O to bring in other imports.  And I haven't found a way to go back and just click on the method to have it automatically bring them back.

Comment: I'm a little bit lost in all the discussion of static imports. I usually use them, sorry I was inconsistent, I was just hacking out an attempt and IntelliJ gets strongarmed about this sometimes.

Comment: @WJS I don't have `Map.of()` any more than I have `List.of()` ;)

Comment: @orbfish  Of course. My oversight.  I find it hard to remember what release introduced certain features.  But that one should have been obvious to me.